# Ways to synch many (small) files over high-latency network connection

Tags: svn, synchronization, rsync, cwrsync

We typically deploy our software applications to our clients using Subversion (svn update on the clients; unidirectional). We're currently experiencing problems with one of our clients because of the high latency (large file download speeds are good) because they are in China and our server is in Canada. Subversion simply times out with an error after a very long period of time.

Our application has lots of small files (.aspx, .config, etc.) and a few larger files (.dll, .jpg) for a total of about 100mb-200mb.

I am currently considering doing the following:

1. Do a local svn checkout on the server
2. Zip the result
3. FTP or rsync the large zip file to
   the foreign machine
4. Unzipping the file in a temporary
   folder.
5. Doing a local rsync from that temp
   folder to our typical installation
   folder.

Are there any better solutions?

- Setting up a Subversion mirror closer
  to the destination?  (I would only need it up a few hours a month but might be hard to find)
- Using another version control system? (Is git any
  better for high-latency connections)?
- Are there ways to package subversion
  patches (including binary files) to
  be reapplied at the destination
  instead of sending all of the data?
- Would using DropBox (which uses Amazon S3) to transfer files into the temporary folder be any better?

Comment: >> "Are there ways to package subversion patches (including binary files) to be reapplied at the destination instead of sending all of the data?" // 
You're describing git.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't knock rsync for the whole tree of small files until you've given it a shot. It doesn't do a round-trip for every single file, it's pipelined, so it should be as fast as anything else on the whole dataset. (As fast as TCP can reassemble the frames into ordered packets on your high-latency link.)

Check out [how rsync works](http://www.samba.org/rsync/how-rsync-works.html) for explanation of how it avoids round-trips.

Comment: I am currently running a test. Seems we have a winner. I was assuming is was doing a file-by-file transfer, but it appears I was mistaken!

Comment: In my tests, it ran slower (approx 10x) than FTP but did not crash like Subversion and will not need to redownload the same content during the next execution.

Answer (score 2):

You could create a unix style patch of all changes across all files.  And just transfer that in a zip file.

Comment: You would have to roll your own to do this.  I don't think subversion does this out of the box.

Comment: +1 even though wouldn't work for binaries.  And TortoiseSVN can apply patches to working copies.

Comment: This sounds a little too involved to me, and using TortoiseSVN in a terminal services session on the remote end is going to be brutal where every click takes 3 seconds to register.

Comment: Patch should handle binaries too.  It should track all changes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [git](http://git-scm.org) (perhaps with git-svn) to handle the transfer. Its amazingly efficient for moving differences in file versions.

Otherwise, you can use an xdiff binary diff tool.